# SPI communication Problem Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, spi

I'm trying to set up SPI communication between two Arduinos (UNO and Mega),
I want to read the status of the slave output pin from the master.

I connected a diode to pin 9 of Mega and I wanted to display its state on the virtual terminal of the master (Uno). The problem is that when the LED flashes I do not receive values just at the terminal level but when I hold it to zero or 1 the display is correct.
I used another code I found online.

MASTER code

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
const byte btn =8;

void setup(void) {

Serial.begin (9600);
pinMode (btn, INPUT_PULLUP);
digitalWrite (SS, HIGH);
SPI.begin ();
SPI.setClockDivider (SPI_CLOCK_DIV8);

}

void loop(void) {

byte Mvalsent,Mvalreceived;
digitalWrite (SS, LOW);
for (int jj=0; jj<255; jj++)
  {
      Mvalsent =jj;
      Mvalreceived =SPI.transfer (Mvalsent);
      Serial.print ("Retou d'etat ");
      Serial.print (Mvalsent);
      Serial.print ("\t ,l'etat de la diode est ");
      Serial.println (Mvalreceived);
      delay (400);
  }

  digitalWrite (SS,HIGH);

}
```

SLAVE Code

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
byte state;
const byte led =9; 
volatile boolean process_it;
volatile byte Svalreceived, Svalsent;
int jj=0;
void setup (void)
{
  Serial.begin (9600);
pinMode (led,OUTPUT);
//set MISO pin as output
pinMode (MISO, OUTPUT);
//turn on SPI in slave mode
SPCR |= _BV (SPE);
//get ready for an interrupt
process_it = false;
//now turn on interrupts
SPI.attachInterrupt ();
}
ISR (SPI_STC_vect)
{
  Svalreceived = SPDR;
  process_it =true;
}
void loop (void)
{
 if (process_it)
 {

   digitalWrite (led, LOW);
   state =digitalRead(led);
   SPDR = state;
   Serial.print("l'etat de la diode est: ");
    Serial.println (state);
    delay (400);


    process_it =false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not too familiar with arduino, but this seems to be a simple case of sampling.  You also need to clarify what you mean by "I do not receive values just at the terminal level" - do you get always incorrect values? Random values? Or does it not read at all?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use I2C slave-master between arduinos?  You can hook up other arduinos or devices on I2C simultaneously (as long as each uses a distinct address).

And you still keep the SPI for a microsd card adapter, for example.

Follow [this official tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterWriter):

[image]

MASTER ARDUINO 1

```
// Wire Master Writer
// by Nicholas Zambetti <http://www.zambetti.com>

// Demonstrates use of the Wire library
// Writes data to an I2C/TWI slave device
// Refer to the "Wire Slave Receiver" example for use with this

// Created 29 March 2006

// This example code is in the public domain.


#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(); // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
}

byte x = 0;

void loop() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(8); // transmit to device #8
  Wire.write("x is ");        // sends five bytes
  Wire.write(x);              // sends one byte
  Wire.endTransmission();    // stop transmitting

  x++;
  delay(500);
}
```

SLAVE ARDUINO 2

```
// Wire Slave Receiver
// by Nicholas Zambetti <http://www.zambetti.com>

// Demonstrates use of the Wire library
// Receives data as an I2C/TWI slave device
// Refer to the "Wire Master Writer" example for use with this

// Created 29 March 2006

// This example code is in the public domain.


#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(8);                // join i2c bus with address #8
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
  Serial.begin(9600);           // start serial for output
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
}

// function that executes whenever data is received from master
// this function is registered as an event, see setup()
void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
  while (1 < Wire.available()) { // loop through all but the last
    char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
    Serial.print(c);         // print the character
  }
  int x = Wire.read();    // receive byte as an integer
  Serial.println(x);         // print the integer
}
```

This is an alternative example of a setup using a nodemcu (which doesnt function in slave mode, btw).

[image]